# I'm using a weather forecasting code on jupyter notebook python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am working on a machine learning linear regression based project on weather forecasting. I used the following code but I'm getting the error `only 2 arguments accepted`
Code is shown below:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
X=df.drop(['PrecipitationSumInches'], axis=1)
Y=df['PrecipitationSumInches']
Y=Y.values.reshape(-1,1)
day_index=798
days=[i for i in range(Y.size)]
clf=LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X,Y)
inp=np.array([74],[60],[45],[67],[49],[43],[33],[45],[57], 
[29.68],[10],[7],[2],[0],[20],[4],[31])
inp=inp.reshape(1,-1)
print("The Precipitation in inches for the input is:",
clf.predict(inp))
```

Comment: Unless we know how your X is structured, it is difficult to say how your inp should be.

Comment: Sir please check the code now, I have edited it providing X as well. 
    X=df.drop(['PrecipitationSumInches'], 
    axis=1)                                                             
    Y=df['PrecipitationSumInches']

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to create an array with numpy.

Change

```
inp=np.array([74],[60],[45],[67],[49],[43],[33],[45],[57],[29.68],[10],[7],[2],[0],[20],[4],[31])
```

To:

```
inp=np.array([74,60,45,67,49,43,33,45,57,29.68,10,7,2,0,20,4,31])
```

And please, the next time format your code and add error trace.

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick response. I made the changes and now I'm getting the following error: valueerror:matmul:Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0,with gufunc signature (n?, k), (k, m?) - >(n?, m?) (size 16 is different from 17)

Comment: Please provide the shape of X and Y. Probably your training data was of shape 16 and now your're using 17, but unless your provide the shape of the data, the error trace, the code etc we can't know

Comment: Here's my X and Y 
    X=df.drop(['PrecipitationSumInches'], 
    axis=1)           
    Y=df['PrecipitationSumInches']  
    Y=Y.values.reshape(-1,1)

Comment: If you don't provide the df dimensions this means nothing

Comment: Sir I used 'df' command and it prints:                      1319 rows * 17 columns.  Does this help?

Comment: Sir I think my dataset represents 1319 rows and 17 columns so does this info suffice for you to hell me out in the error I'm getting

Comment: So, if your df has 17 columns but you drop one the final X has 16 columns. But in your code you're trying to predict with 17 values so it fails. Something's wrong with your data.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here.  Let's take a step back and solve a simple regression problem, the canonical Boston Housing problem.  Copy/paste the code below into your Python environment, run it, check the results, and post back if you still have questions.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
#%matplotlib inline
import sklearn

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()

# Now we will load the data into a pandas dataframe and then will print the first few rows of the data using the head() function.
bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)
bos.head()


bos.columns = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT']
bos.head()

bos['MEDV'] = boston.target


bos.describe()

bos.isnull().sum()



sns.distplot(bos['MEDV'])
plt.show()
```

[image]
    sns.pairplot(bos)

[image]

```
corr_mat = bos.corr().round(2)
```

[image]

```
sns.heatmap(data=corr_mat, annot=True)
```

[image]

```
sns.lmplot(x = 'RM', y = 'MEDV', data = bos)
```

[image]

```
X = bos[['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX','PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT']]
y = bos['MEDV']


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 10)

# Training the Model
# We will now train our model using the LinearRegression function from the sklearn library.

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Prediction
# We will now make prediction on the test data using the LinearRegression function and plot a scatterplot between the test data and the predicted value.

prediction = lm.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(y_test, prediction)
```

[image]

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted':prediction})
df2 = df1.head(10)
df2

df2.plot(kind = 'bar')

from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
print('MAE', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, prediction))
print('MSE', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, prediction))
print('RMSE', np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, prediction)))
print('R squared error', r2_score(y_test, prediction))
```

Result:

```
MAE 4.061419182954711
MSE 34.413968453138565
RMSE 5.866341999333023
R squared error 0.6709339839115628
```

https://acadgild.com/blog/linear-regression-on-boston-housing-data

Also, check this out.

https://github.com/chatkausik/Linear-Regression-using-Boston-Housing-data-set/blob/master/Mini_Project_Linear_Regression.ipynb

There are other, similar, examples online.  Check out the Iris data set and try to do regression on that.   There are so many examples.  Copy/paste some simple code, get it working, and come back here with questions, if you still have questions (a lot of these things are self-evident).  Remember, you get out of it, what you put into it.

Comment: That's great, hope it will help